# cetic-nifi Invalid host header issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, apache-nifi

- Helm version: v3.5.2
- Kubernetes version: v1.20.4
- nifi chart version:latest : 1.0.2   [rel](https://github.com/cetic/helm-nifi/releases/tag/1.0.2)
- Issue: [[cetic/nifi]-issue](https://github.com/cetic/helm-nifi/issues/199)

I'm trying to connect to nifi UI deployed in kubernetes.

I have set following properties in values yaml

```
properties:
  # use externalSecure for when inbound SSL is provided by nginx-ingress or other external mechanism
  sensitiveKey: changeMechangeMe # Must to have minimal 12 length key
  algorithm: NIFI_PBKDF2_AES_GCM_256
  externalSecure: false
  isNode: false
  httpsPort: 8443 

  webProxyHost: 10.0.39.39:30666
  clusterPort: 6007
  
  # ui service
service:
  type: NodePort
  httpsPort: 8443
  nodePort: 30666
  annotations: {}
    # loadBalancerIP:
    ## Load Balancer sources
    ## https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/#restrict-access-for-loadbalancer-service
    ##
    # loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    # - 10.10.10.0/24
    ## OIDC authentication requires "sticky" session on the LoadBalancer for JWT to work properly...but AWS doesn't like it on creation
    # sessionAffinity: ClientIP
    # sessionAffinityConfig:
    #   clientIP:
  #     timeoutSeconds: 10800
```

10.0.39.39 - is the kubernetes masternode internal ip.

When nifi get started i get follwoing

```
 WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is group-readable. This is insecure. Location: /home/k8sadmin/.kube/config
WARNING: Kubernetes configuration file is world-readable. This is insecure. Location: /home/k8sadmin/.kube/config
NAME: nifi
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Nov 25 12:38:00 2021
NAMESPACE: jeed-cluster
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
Cluster endpoint IP address will be available at:
kubectl get svc nifi -n jeed-cluster -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[*].ip}'

Cluster endpoint domain name is: 10.0.39.39:30666 - please update your DNS or /etc/hosts accordingly!

Once you are done, your NiFi instance will be available at:

  https://10.0.39.39:30666/nifi
```

and when i do a curl

```
curl https://10.0.39.39:30666 put sample.txt -k

<h1>System Error</h1>
<h2>The request contained an invalid host header [<code>10.0.39.39:30666</
the request [<code>/</code>]. Check for request manipulation or third-part
t.</h2>
<h3>Valid host headers are [<code>empty
<ul><li>127.0.0.1</li>
<li>127.0.0.1:8443</li>
<li>localhost</li>
<li>localhost:8443</li>
<li>[::1]</li>
<li>[::1]:8443</li>
<li>nifi-0.nifi-headless.jeed-cluste
<li>nifi-0.nifi-headless.jeed-cluste
<li>10.42.0.8</li>
<li>10.42.0.8:8443</li>
<li>0.0.0.0</li>
<li>0.0.0.0:8443</li>
</ul>
```

- Tried lot of things but still cannot whitelist master node ip in
  proxy hosts
- Ingress is not used
- edit: it looks like properties set in values.yaml is not set in nifi.properties in side the pod. Is there any reason for this?

Appreciate help!

Comment: The chart doesn't have an option to set webHttpsHost , from where did you get this property ? Also what is the purpose to whitelist k8s master ?

Comment: just ignore that. I  have tried several ways even without it. Does not work :(  
Purpose to whitelist k8s master : its the access point to the cluster.  it should be able to white list either k8s master or the LB infront of it. But cannot add any host to whitelist

Answer (score 0):

As NodePort service you can also assign port number from 30000-32767.

You can apply values when you install your chart with:

properties:
webProxyHost: localhost
httpsPort:

This should let nifi whitelist your https://localhost: